# Connection String Class and correct way to use texbox inputs?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, oracle, connection

I have windows form application and below component C#... also I created connection class for my connection string. What is the best way to use textBox inside my connection string? should I create getters and setters class for textBox inputs to generate parameter and use it inside my connection string? Please give me example... Thanks!

***My TextBoxes***

> userDataSourceTextBox
>
> userIDTextBox
>
> userPasswordTextBox

***Myconnection Class***

```
class Connection
    {
        public static OracleConnection getConnection()
        {
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + userDataSourceTextBox.Text + ";User Id=" + usernameTextBox.Text.ToUpper() + ";Password=" + userPasswordTextBox.Text + ";");
            return con;
        }
    }
```

***MainForm***

```
               OracleConnection conn1 = Connection.getConnection() 
               conn1.Open();

                using (OracleCommand Names = new OracleCommand("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME", conn1))
                {
                    using (OracleDataReader reader = Names.ExecuteReader())
                    {                            
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {                                    
                            //Do something                              
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should think about what you're trying to achieve with the class more. Why would a `Connection` class ever have a dependency on a UI widget?

Comment: In addition: a static class is not the ideal way to go here. Since even the connection object is not static (your changing it according to the user input).

Comment: Also, your Connection type should implement IDisposable and Close it's connection when disposed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass my getters and setters parameters to connection class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580960/how-can-i-pass-my-getters-and-setters-parameters-to-connection-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code its obvious you dont have proper code structure in place. Never couple UI and DAL layer. UI and DAL layers should be completely de-coupled.

A common approach is something like this:

> UI Layer -> Business Layer -> Data Access layer - Persistence storage (DB, file, etc...)

In your case, you can change `GetConnection()` as parameterized method and pass the required values to it.

```
    class Connection
    {
        public static OracleConnection GetConnection(string dataSource, string userName, string password)
        {
            OracleConnection con = null;
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataSource) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                {
                    con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + dataSource + ";User Id=" + userName.ToUpper() + ";Password=" + password + ";");
                    return con;
                }

            return con;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The use of the static is really bad. It has no use here

Comment: @BobClaerhout: Since this method doesn't use any instance fields, it certainly should be static.

Comment: gives error at 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOfEmpty'

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`OracleConnectionStringBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), which builds connection strings from individual components.

Comment: I agree with @Slaks all what you Need the string builder example: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder builder =
   new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "OracleDemo";
builder["integrated Security"] = true;
builder["User ID"] = "Mary;NewValue=Bad";
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);